# direct limit and inverse limit

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Consider R-Mod.
we know there is a induced map
$ \theta:\lim_{\rightarrow_i}\lim_{\leftarrow_j}M_{ij}\longrightarrow \lim_{\leftarrow_j}\lim_{\rightarrow_i}M_{ij}$.

- if we consider coproducts and products,$\theta$ is monic.
- but in general, is $\theta$ monic?

Comment: Even in the case of products and coproducts, $\theta$ is not monic in every category. In fact, the map $\theta$ is self-dual, that is if you consider the same systems in the opposite category, you switch between projective and injective limits and change the direction of arrows, but $\theta$ does not change. So even if it is true in the category of abelian groups that $\bigoplus_i\prod_j M_{ij}\rightarrow \prod_j\bigoplus_i M_{ij}$ is monic, in the opposite of category of abelian group, this map is epic.

Comment: @Roland you are right.I forget to say in the category of module.

Comment: Are "direct limit" and "inverse limit" still the right words to use in the case of coproducts and products? I thought those terms were only used for filtered colimits and filtered limits respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z}@>{\times 2}>>\mathbb{Z}\\
@VVV@VVV\\
\mathbb{Z/2Z}@>0>>\mathbb{Z/2Z}
\end{CD}
$$
where the vertical maps are the canonical projections. We will show that the cokernels of the map induced between the kernels of the vertical maps is not a subgroup of the kernel of the maps between the cokernel of the horizontal maps. It will be a counter-example of the assertion.

On one hand, the kernels of the vertical maps are
$$2\mathbb{Z}\overset{\times 2}\longrightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}$$
So $\operatorname{coker}\ker=\mathbb{2Z/4Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z/2Z}$.

On the other hand, the cokernels of the horizontal maps are 
$$\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z/2Z}\\ @VV\operatorname{id}V \\ \mathbb{Z/2Z}
\end{CD}$$
So $\ker\operatorname{coker}=0$. In follows that the map $\theta:\operatorname{coker}\ker\rightarrow\ker\operatorname{coker}$ cannot be into.

Comment: If $f,g:A\rightarrow B$,then direct limit is $coker(f-g)$,but for$f:A\rightarrow B$the direct limit is not $cokerf$,you should calculate it by definition.For finite index,I think this is right.

Comment: Yes I should have said that to be a counter-example with injective and projective limits instead of ker and coker, you should add in the commutative square 4 morphisms, each 0 and parallel to the 4 already present. Now $\ker f$ and $\operatorname{coker}f$ are respectively limits and colimits with respect to $A\overset{f}{\underset{0}\rightrightarrows} B$.

Comment: yeah,add four trivial arrow.your example is a very good counterexample!thank you very much!